# Steps to enable the Maven integration with eclipse

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mahout

I have installed maven and eclipse juno, on CentOS. Can anyone guide me how to integrate Eclipse with maven. I am going to use this configuration for Mahout.

Comment: Could you be more specific? How would you like to integrate the 2? I believe Eclipse now comes bundled with the m2eclipse plugin built in for Maven integration.

Comment: Kepler doesn't come with m2e pre-installed.  I had to go grab it.

Comment: My mistake. Either way, the m2eclipse plugin is a good way to start for Eclipse/Maven integration.

Comment: Download the Java EE edition next time.  Also Juno is old, use Kepler.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04, I tried with kepler, luna and JUNO eclipse. But Finally JUNO integration with Maven is perfect one. I am able to chose the project type as Maven. For Juno tar file for Ubuntu you can refer  the link http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/eclipse//technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR2/eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download maven from from eclipse market place
Simply go to help -> eclipse market place, then search maven.
(Though i have always got it already integrated in eclipse).

After you can make various customizations to suite your needs by selecting, window -> preferences, then type in maven in the search bar ontop, you can configure the location of your settings.xml file, maven installation to use and other things you may want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a plugin for eclipse so that it knows what to do about maven projects (such as [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/)).

Once you have that installed, you can configure it (Windows -> Preferences -> Maven) to point to your existing maven installation, and can then create maven projects via the New -> Maven Project wizard.

You can also convert existing project to maven projects via a right click -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your post. I followed the following steps.
>open eclipse >go to help >Eclipse Market Place> search for m2Eclipse >select the product maven integrated with eclipse JUNO
After installation I was able to see the Maven option in Windows --> Preferences